# Performance issue: Components library following the dot notation structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I decided to follow the dot notation to create my components library like [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) does:

```html
<Card>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

To do it you need to graft the children components (like `CardBody`) to the 'main' component (here `Card`) just like that:

```js
const Card = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>
const CardBody = () => <>Body</>

Card.Body = CardBody

export default Card
```

So that you can use all the children of `Card` very easily:

```js
import Card from 'my-component-library/card'

<Card>
  <Card.Body>
  ...
```

This type of structure is used in a lot of components library but after reflection, I realize that with this structure, the `import Card from 'my-component-library/card'` is a significant action because under the hood there can be dozens of components that are imported and not used (like `Card.Header` or `Card.Text`).

So my question is: Is there a significant performance problem in this structure? Should I keep the default 'import useful component' structure like this?

```js
import Card from 'my-component-library/card'
import CardBody from 'my-component-library/cardBody'

<Card>
  <CardBody>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Very good question!

There are two points to discuss.

**Point #1 - size and treeshaking.**

When you are using

```
import {MyComponent} from './MyComponent'
```

Webpack (or other bundler) can shake the tree :) and take only that code you will really use.

In the case of

```
import * from 'MyLib'
```

You import everything (for your case as well). Usually, it's not a problem, but if you design the library - this is a really important point to take into consideration.

**Point #2 - performance.**

What happens when you importing the module?

- Object allocated
- javascript executed

What do I mean. Let's check this code:

*some module*

```js
const MyComponent1 = (x) => `hello ${x}`;
const MyComponent2 = (y) => `good bye ${x}`

const data = Array.from(Array(1000)).fill(Date.now());
const MyComponent3 = () => `dates: ${data}.map((x, i)=> ...)`
```

When we importing this module, as far as it is in one file JS engine will:
* create 3 new functions, 
* allocate 1 very big array.

This, of course, will need some time and memory. If we are going with a classic approach this will not a problem, because you split the code and move that to the separate files and related code will be executed **only** when you import them. In your approach - they will be executed in any case. For the library, this is also the important point.

That's actually it. Try both approaches, do some checks and pick an option that fits you the best.

Comment: First thanks for your answer and time but I still have some questions. `You import everything...Usually, it's not a problem...important point to take into consideration`: Why is it usually not a problem?

Comment: Because 90% of times we are building applications rather than libraries. And if you are building an application, probably all of your components will be included in the app. So no matter how it will be included. 
In the case of the library, I want to get only the things I need. @johannchopin

Comment: Well now I understand your point. So in this case it's definitively not a good practice to do it. But why is it recommended by React itself and used by popular libraries like react-bootstrap (614,716 Weekly Downloads)?

Comment: I don't have a 100% sure answer. The one good reason is that this saves from naming collision. The second point is because many people believe that usability is over performance. But the second point is to holyvaric to discuss it here :)